# Does WinRT BackgroundTransfer support HTTP Content-Range for resumable downloads?

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, resume-download, http-content-range

I need to download large files (200MB) in the background, and it should be resumable in case of interruptions. The server side supports Range Headers so just wondering if this is a supported scenario in BackgroundTransfer agent of WinRT from which we can make Range-Header HTTP calls to download the file.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br207242.aspx

HTTP Content-Range requests: 
http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.16

Answer (score 1):

The whole point of `BackgroundTransfer` is that it's run on the background by the system. That means the OS decides when the download is run and it's independent of when your app runs. Specifically, the download can run when your app doesn't run, but it also may be paused when your app is running (for example, when the device is not connected to a Wi-Fi and you have [`BackgroundTransferCostPolicy.AvoidNetworkCharges`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.networking.backgroundtransfer.backgroundtransfercostpolicy.aspx) set).

All this means that you can't set `Content-Range` by yourself, but it is used automatically when necessary.